# Classic ASP - Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80040e14'

Tags: sql, vb.net, iis

I've migrated an ASP Classic application from an IIS 6 to IIS 10 and am running into this issue:

```
Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80040e14'

[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]DATABASE.dbo.proc_Center_Price_List_Stock 93, 1, NULL, 1, NULL, 383

/modules/orders/Order.asp, line 57
```

Here's the code around line 57 in ***Order.asp***:

```
   56 - rsStockItem.CursorLocation = adUseClient
   57 - rsStockItem.Open SQL, myConn, adOpenDynamic
```

here's the db method:

```
<%
Dim myConn
Dim strCnn

Set myConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

strCnn = "Driver={SQL Server}; Server=(local)\SQLEXPRESS; Database=DATABASE; UID=USER; PWD=1234567890"

myConn.ConnectionTimeOut = 180
myConn.CommandTimeOut = 180
myConn.Open strCnn
%>
```

Things I have checked:

- Database connection - successful
- DB user permission  - successful
- Pool configuration - checked
- Error in Stored Procedure *proc_Center_Price_List_Stock* - No error

can anybody help?

Comment: try t use set at the starting of this line rsStockItem.CursorLocation = adUseClient and check all the syntax you are using is correct or not.

Comment: @JalpaPanchal Thanks for your assistance, unfortunately, all syntax is correct

Comment: You need to capture more error information.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/guide/data/ado-errors?view=sql-server-2017  And it's odd that you get an error from `Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers`, which is MSDASQL, not the OleDb provider used in your connection string.